# Will Paginate can order by certain columns but not by other columns on Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am doing some maintenance on a Rails 2 application using Ruby 1.8.7. I am using will_paginate.

I have the following problem:
When calling current_user.products.paginate(:page => 1, :order => "**updated_at asc**") it orders, as expected, based on the updated_at property in products.

However, when calling current_user.products.paginate(:page => 1, :order => "**released_at asc**") it does not order on released_at as expected. In fact it doesn't matter whether I specify ordering to happen according to "asc" or "desc", I get the same collection returned.

updated_at and released_at are both attributes defined on the model and exists in the database and all values are non-null. There is no default_scope defined on the models.

What could be causing this and how to correct this?

Adding Desc products below (for brevity I am only listing the relevant fields):

| Field           | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

| released_at     | datetime  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| updated_at      | datetime  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

Comment: It would be nice to see the sql-query from the log.

Comment: SQL query from non-working paginate statement in log: SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (`products`.partner_id = 171) ORDER BY released_at desc LIMIT 0, 50 and SQL query from working paginate statemnet in log: SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (`products`.partner_id = 171) ORDER BY updated_at desc LIMIT 0, 50.

Comment: can you also DESC products from mysql so we can see the data types?

Comment: Just added DESC products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Product model inherits from a model that also defines the released_at attribute. The method for released_at is overloaded in the Ruby on Rails code so that if one would call product.released_at on an instance product of Product, then it would actually call the released_at value on the parent model. As a result, from the rails console it always looks as if released_at is not null and contains a value.

However, looking at the database directly shows that released_at is null in the Product model and as such, even though the will_paginate request goes through correctly, no ordering is done because the values are all the same (null). In the case where the exact same query is performed on the updated_at attribute, sorting works because that attribute is not null. I missed this because I checked for empty values from the Rails Console rather than in MySQL directly.

My solution was to define a named_scope on the Product model that sorts based on the value in the parent model. I then call the paginate function on the named scope.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it need to have an index defined for ordering fields to make it working.

Comment: What does this mean? Please clarify.

Comment: I mean DataBase indexes for columns.

Comment: When I call the SQL command directly in MySQL it orders correctly. So I don't think it's this issue.